# Extract value from its key using SQL

Tags: mysql, dictionary

I want to extract value from a column using its key. The data is stored as a dictionary. I want the values of "hotel_id" from the column.

Data in column is stored like this: (Examples)

["search_params": {"region": "PK", "sort_by": "POPULARITY", "currency": "PKR", "hotel_id": "688867", "slot_only": false, "segment_id": "6f9a9cc5-be52-4ae4-b5d2-cc19c6753085", "occupancies": [{"rooms": 1, "adults": 2, "children": 0, "child_age_list": []}], "check_in_date": "2022-11-13"]

[ "search_result": {"hotel_dict": {"241825": {"source": 3, "hotel_id": 241825, "availability": {"rooms": {"rooms_id_list": [3187909, 3187910, 3187911, 3187912], "rooms_data_dict": {"3187909": {"room_id": 3187909, "rate_options": [{"adult": 3, "child": 0, "bar_rate": 7500, "rate_key": "542984|991065", "extra_bed": 0, "occupancy": {"2": 1}]

I tried a query but it works for specific number of characters and does not ignore spaces and commas (dirty data).

> 

```
    SELECT substr(substr(info, instr(info, 'hotel_id') + 11),
    2,
    instr(substr(info, instr(info, 'hotel_id') + 1), '"') - 2
    ) result
from df
```

The result I get is:

> result
> 0   688867
> 1   41825,
> 2   41771,
> 3   394910
> 4   ull, "
> 5   394910

Comment: If the data is stored as valid json within the column then you can use mysql's json function to search in the column. If not, then you should normalise your data, otherwise forget this.

Comment: So there is no way to do this inside the database? Without json.

Comment: Mysql has a limited set of text manipulation functions. With those you basically have to write a piece of code that parses a dictionary structure **and** does this with an acceptable speed. No, I would not try this if you cannot use json functions, which provide features like this.